# Add MongoDB v3.4 cluster to Percona Monitoring and Management v2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-eks, percona, pmm-server

Is it possible to add MongoDB v3.4 cluster to Percona Monitoring and Management v2? Can't use PMM1 because I can't deploy it in EKS.

The documentation says that MongoDB version v4.0 and higher is supported.
I also tried to deploy PMM1 in EKS, but it doesn't work. Nginx in pmm1 container crashes.

Comment: Sounds like a question that may be better for the vendor directly?